# How to install numpy on Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: python, java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot

I am using Elastic Beanstalk to host my spring boot application (generating jar package based on maven), in my spring boot project I need to read python script, the python script contains numpy and matplotlib. It works fine locally . Elastic Beanstalk helps me run the python script, but Elastic Beanstalk is missing numpy and matplotlib and I get this error when I run :

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/var/app/current/application.py", line 1, in import numpy as np ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

Can anyone tell me how to install numpy and matplotlib on Elastic Beanstalk ？

Answer (score 0):

Installing packages is explained in [Packages documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-packages). Basically you have to create `.ebextensions` folder with the files describing packages that you want to install.

Comment: hi,I created the .ebextensions folder and Created 01.config file in .ebextensions folder , in 01.config i wrote:
packages:
  yum:
    numpy:[]

but it still doesn't work