# How do i push my updated code to elastic beanstalk(eb)?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, numpy, flask

I am sure this is super simple, but I can't figure it out to save my life!

I was trying to upload my flask app to eb and I was getting some dependencies errors.

I then tried to upload the simplest Flask app to eb and I was still getting dependencies errors!

it seems like there is an issue with numpy + flask + elastic beanstalk.
The app that I am trying to upload only contains the following dependencies:

```
click==8.1.6
Flask==2.2.2
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.2
MarkupSafe==2.1.3
numpy==1.21.2
Werkzeug==2.3.6
```

If I remove numpy it works perfectly, which is weird because numpy is a very popular package.

I found a very similar issue and their solution didnt work:: [How to install numpy on Elastic Beanstalk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73520801/how-to-install-numpy-on-elastic-beanstalk)

I have created a .ebextensions folder, it contains a file called 01_flask.config with the following code::

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    PYTHONPATH: "/var/app/current:$PYTHONPATH"
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: "application:app"

packages:
  yum:
    numpy: []
    python3-matplotlib: []
```

I also have the folder .elasticbeanstalk folder with contains the file called config.yml with the following code::

```
branch-defaults:
  master:
    environment: python-flask-todo-dev
  mysql:
    environment: python-flask-todo-dev
    group_suffix: null
global:
  application_name: python-flask-todo
  branch: null
  default_ec2_keyname: null
  default_platform: Python 3.8
  default_region: us-east-1
  include_git_submodules: true
  instance_profile: null
  platform_name: null
  platform_version: null
  profile: eb-cli
  repository: null
  sc: git
  workspace_type: Application
```

this is what the app.py looks like::

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.get("/")


def home():
    return render_template("base.html")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

here are the eb-engine.log ::https://docs.google.com/document/d/1m05kjRuOIA_j7GOhkW7cNtUMowxXaXaLASOCsNOMmD0/edit

does any have any idea whats going on?

Comment: The relevant error in the 200 page document is `error: PyObjC requires macOS to build`